# Rails: form_tag multiple path(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a search-form where I want to find both users and places, is it possible to put multiple paths in the form? I want to use the same textfield to find what I want but in different index pages like if I'm searching for a user the list will be filled with users... and if I want to find places, yeah you get the idea I hope.

```
  <%= form_tag [venues_path, user_path], :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Search..." %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: No,You can do via javascript to submit to path via ajax and combined result but better way is use same function and search for venue and user and combined result and display result

Comment: All right! Thanks! But I think I just solved it. I created a new controller with something like this:

def index
[AT]venues = Venue.all
[AT]users = User.all
end 

and so on. It works out the way I want it so. :)

Comment: use same function and search for venue and user and combined result and display result is same as what u did

Comment: I see, well thanks anyway!