# Rails multiple form_tag paths/implement global search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316326/rails-form-tag-multiple-paths) but still can't figure it out.

I am creating a rails app linked to a Neo4j database and have a number of models I want to search across with one search form. I am using elastic search.

**My current code for searching within one model (works fine):**

```
#/app/views/symptoms/index.html
<%=form_tag symptoms_path, class: "form-inline", method: :get do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control" %>    
    <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% if params[:query].present? %>    
    <%= link_to "clear" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

#/app/controllers/symptoms_controller.rb
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @symptoms = Symptom.search(params[:query], show: params[:show])
  else
    @symptoms = Symptom.all
  end
end
```

Currently this will only search within the symptoms model. I want to to create a 'global search' field that will search within the symptoms_path, allergies_path, and drugs_path.

**Potential 'Global Search' code:**

```
#/app/views/global_search/index.html
<%=form_tag [symptoms_path, allergies_path, drugs_path], class: "form-inline", method: :get do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control" %>    
    <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% if params[:query].present? %>    
    <%= link_to "clear" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

#/app/controllers/symptoms_controller.rb
def index
    if params[:query].present?
        @allergies = Allergy.search(params[:query], show: params[:show])
        @drugs = Drug.search(params[:query])
        @symptoms = Symptom.search(params[:query])
    else
        @allergies = Allergy.all
        @drugs = Drug.all
        @symptoms = Symptom.all
    end
end
```

Any ideas for how I could implement this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably suggest that you create something like a "search_controller" (`rails generate controller search` should help you do that).  In there you can have an `index` action (or whatever you want to call your action) and then you just set up a route to point a URL to it such as this:

```
# config/routes.rb
  # Link the URL to the search controller's `index` action
  post '/search/:query' => 'search#index'

# app/controllers/search_controller.rb

  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @allergies = Allergy.search(params[:query], show: params[:show])
      @drugs = Drug.search(params[:query])
      @symptoms = Symptom.search(params[:query])
    else
      @allergies = Allergy.all
      @drugs = Drug.all
      @symptoms = Symptom.all
    end
  end
```

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, I'm not sure how much you've worked with Rails before

Comment: Oh not much, I've been teaching myself over the last couple months. But you saved the day again, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again, Brian!

Comment: Glad to hear it ;)  I know it can be a bit confusing because examples generally have controllers just revolving around models.

Comment: Yes it took me a bit to understand that concept, there have been lots of fun aha! moments :)